# Loading JSON into data tables

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatable

I have a Web API built with ASP.NET MVC. The results of hitting that API look something like this:

```
{
  "RequestID":1,
  "Options": [
    {"Id":"A", "Name":"Alpha"},
    {"Id":"B", "Name":"Bravo"}
  ],
  "Responses":[
    {"Id":123, "Name":"Test 1", "Description":"This is the first response"},
    {"Id":222, "Name":"Test 2", "Description":"This is the second response"},
    {"Id":333, "Name":"Test 3", "Description":"This is the third response"},
  ]
}
```

I want to load the response of the Web API into a data table using the [DataTables plugin](http://datatables.net/). In an attempt to do this, I have the following:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="properties" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th class="sortable">Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#properties').dataTable({
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    'url':'/api/Search?query=Test'
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I based the implementation off of the example found [here](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html). My problem is, it doesn't work. Its like the data table doesn't know to use the Responses property as the data set for the data table. However, I can't figure out how to set that.

Does someone know how I can load the objects in the `Responses` array into the data table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

Since, cannot access your API, I could't verify the below. But it should work fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#properties').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                'url':'/api/Search?query=Test',
                "dataSrc": "Responses"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order for DataTables to display your data, it must be formatted in a way that DataTables can understand. See http://datatables.net/manual/server-side for the reference. Look under the heading *Returned data*.

Specifically, your JSON needs to put the data under a parameter called *data* (instead of *Responses*).

You also need to include the *draw*, *recordsTotal*,and *recordsFildered* parameters.

If you are not able to modify your web API to suit the DataTables format, you would need to use another approach. Two that come to mind are either writing an intermediary service that translates the output of the web API into the right format for DataTables, or using JavaScript to manually read the output of the web API and insert the rows into your table.